# How to create partial view which will contain some other controls from the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a filter section which almost all is common for other pages. So I decided to create partial view for it. Though I can't figure out how to pass other controls which are specific for different page.
Example:
[image]

Comment: a partial view shouldn't really contain other controls - it's not a container. For the image above, you would wrap the 3 common items in a partial view, not the whole box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to set the special controls to the ViewBag, and then check for them in the partial and render if they exist.